# Angular 7 routerlink with FIXED parts

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I need to create an new link from the current route:

https://website.com/post/99 = curent browser route

and I need to create this:

https://website.com/**admin**/post/99/**edit**

How to add "admin" and "edit" to this route on angular 7 ?

```
<a [routerLink]="admin/['./']/edit">Edit</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a method in your component :

```
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  getAdminUrl(): string {
    return [
      '/admin',
      'post',
      this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('postId'), // Change with the route parameter id
      'edit',
    ];
  }
```

And use it in your template :

```
<a [routerLink]="getAdminUrl()">Edit</a>
```

Comment: I nedd an more simple solution, -  [routerLink]="['./']" - give me the correct route "post/99" I just need to complete this route with "admin/" at the start, and "/edit" at the end -